P-Value correction across/within multiple datasets
The analysis in my work encompasses a multitude of hypothesis tests and I am not quite sure whether, or how, to control increased false-positive probability. Outside of post-hoc analysis following omnibus tests, I do not have any experience with multiple testing. So please bear with me if my questions are trivial. My study is observational in nature and the data is structured as follows:
The Data
There are 1 to k datasets which can all be divided into 1 to m subgroups. A subgroup represents certain tasks performed by 1 to n subjects. The subjects can be, but do not necessarily need to be, part of all subgroups. A subject is only ever part of one of the k datasets. Within a subgroup a subject is linked to one of 1 to o labels(a descriptive category for the subject) and an outcome variable. For some datasets this outcome variable is continuous, for others categorical(binary). The labels are a grouping variable that indicate similarities among subjects within the respective subgroup but have different meaning between subgroups, such that label i in subgroup 1 has a different meaning from label i in subgroup m.
The structure for an arbitrary dataset looks like this:



subgroup
subject
label
outcome_variable




1
1
1
0.8 / True


1
n
5
0.7 / True


..
..
..
..


m
1
2
0.5 / False


m
n
o
0.9 / True



Testing Hypotheses
For each subgroup in a dataset, I perform an omnibus test with the labels as the independent variable and the outcome variable as the dependent variable.
Anova for the continuous outcome variable:
H0: There are no significant differences among the means of the outcome variable for all levels of the label variable
H1: There are significant differences among the means of the outcome variable for all levels of the label variable
Chi squared test of independence for the categorical outcome variable:
H0: There is no significant relationship between the outcome variable and the label variable
H1:  There is significant relationship between the outcome variable and the label variable
Aggregation
Having performed the tests, I want to aggregate the results. For each of the k datasets the number/percentage of the m subgroups for which the omnibus tests reach significance(alpha=0.05) will be calculated. Finally, I will compare the results across datasets, providing a notion of how often the label variable is associated with the outcome variable for each dataset.
For arbitrary values the results table should look like this:



dataset
n_subgroup
n_subgroup_significant
pct_subgroup_significant




1
11
10
90.9


2
34
17
50.0


....
...
...
...


k
27
8
29.6



Questions

In my research, I have found that the most common cases for p-value adjustment are: 1. tests on subgroups of data with the same dependent variable(e.g., post-hoc after omnibus tests) and 2. tests on the same datasets with different dependent variables. However I have also read that it even makes sense to adjust p-values for tests across multiple datasets when the hypotheses are somewhat thematically related.
My case is more similar to 1. since the outcome variables in all the subgroups have similar meanings (degree of success). What is different is that the subgroups are not just subsets of the data for specific groups of individuals (as in post-hoc tests), but are in itself, for the lack of a better word, 'mini-datasets' and test subjects can be, but do not need to be, part of multiple subgroups.
Do I correctly assume that, given that the hypotheses for all subgroups are the same, p-value adjustment would be prudent?
If I choose to adjust p-values, I need to determine what constitutes a family of hypotheses. Since the datasets are similar in structure but not directly related to each other, controlling the p-values for hypotheses within, and not across, all datasets seems plausible to me.
Does this make sense, given that I aggregate the results and compare them between datasets? Or does the comparison between datasets require a single adjustment across all tests and all datasets?
Subsequently, I need to determine which p-value adjustment method to choose. I have identified several criteria which should have an influence on method selection. First, the study is observational, focusing on explorative data analysis, for which a false positive is not as detrimental as a false positive in, lets say, a medical trial. Secondly, some datasets can have a lot of subgroups(>50). And thirdly, subjects can be part of multiple subgroups which introduces some dependence between tests.
Therefore, controlling the family-wise error rate seems a bit to restrictive to me, and I would prefer to use a method to control the false discovery rate which accounts for dependencies between the tests.
In my opinion, the Benjamini/Yekutieli procedure would seem suitable. Is my reasoning sound?

